# ASP.NET Core MVC Rewrite and Default document

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to set Core MVC Rewrite so:

- when `localhost/part` is requested, it responds with the default `localhost/part/index.html`
- when `localhost/part/[anything]`, then still responds with `index.html` (same `localhost/part/index.html`)

Here's what I have now:

```
    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRewrite("/part(/.*)?$", "index.html", true));

    app.UseIdentity();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
```

I tried different settings, no luck. Is this even possible in ASP.NET Core MVC?

## UPDATE

Here's the code that **kind of** works:

```
    app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRewrite("part(\\/.*)?", "part/index.html", true));

    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseIdentity();
    app.UseMvc(...);
```

So now, when `localhost/part/[anything]/[something]` is requested, it does serve `index.html`. But it serves it as `localhost/part/[anything]/[something]/index.html` and this is a problem with Angular's BASE_HREF. So app shows **Loading...** and nothing else is loaded obviously. Hm... This requires a fix from Angular's part. And I have no idea for the fix right now. Anyone?

Comment: I suggest such question may be simply reduced to "Find regex X" and `regex` tag could be very helpful.

Comment: I actually think my regex is correct. Your proposed solution doesn't work :(

Comment: See my update .

Comment: Try this                 app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRewrite("/part", "index.html", true));

Comment: No. It doesn't work and shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible with correct regex:

```
var options = new RewriteOptions()
    .AddRewrite(@"^part(/)?.*$", "part/index.html", true);
app.UseRewriter(options);

//should be after URL rewrite
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

P.S. I'm not a Regex-guru but let me try.

Comment: @alvipeo are you sure you can hit `index.html` on any path without UrlRewrite? What is `index.html` location?

Comment: `localhost/part` is my Angular 4 app sitting inside ASP.NET Core MVC project. Without the rewrite I can go to `localhost/part` (which actually returns `/part/index.html`) and Angular app just works. The problem is when I hit `localhost/part/users/1` MVC routing starts to handle it and obviously I get 404. But what I want is MVC routing not handle the `/part/[whatever]` at all.

Comment: `UseStaticFiles` should be after `UseRewriter` in pipeline to handle a static file request properly. I've corrected the regex and  got a fully-workable example. See answer for details.

Comment: No, that doesn't help either.

Comment: @alvipeo check how middlewares are triggered in server logs.  `RewriteMiddleware` places a rewrite result there, look at it.

Comment: @alvipeo and try to remove `UseDefaultFiles` call.

Comment: removing UseDefaultFiles didn't fix it

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRewrite("part(.*)", "part/index.html", true));
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseMvc(...);
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work either. Here's the real link from my app `http://localhost:22246/part/directory/patients/new` I'm trying to get working. But NONE of the suggested solutions work.

Comment: see edit, verified this in a poc app. if this doest work, there is some other problem that's not related to the rewrite (the problem was the leading slash)